# Why does a negative value multiplied by -1 not make a positive value after a bitwise operation in Java?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I tried to multiply a negative value by -1 but I'm getting the same negative value itself:

```
long longValue = Long.MAX_VALUE;
int i = (int) (longValue ^ (longValue >>> 32));
int a = i * -1;
//prints -2147483648
System.out.println(i);

//prints -2147483648
System.out.println(a);
```

In the above code both `i` and `a` print a negative value. Why is `a` not assigned a positive value?

Comment: What is `i` before multiplying by `-1`?

Comment: What is the value of `i`? Is it `Integer.MIN_VALUE` perhaps?

Comment: This is a typecasting issue. You're trying to convert value from `long` type to `int` type.

Comment: `i` will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (`-2147483648`) and when you multiply by -1, it *would* be `2147483648`, except that's too big for an int, so it overflows by one, resulting in `-2147483648` again

Comment: @GBlodgett please do not answer in comments